# How to compare two curves on the basis of Hypothesis test

Tags: math, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I have to compare two models based on the plots obtained from the outcome of model using the hypothesis tests.

The data from the first model are:

```
[80.0, 79.73333333333333, 79.46666666666667, 78.8, 78.8, 78.8, 78.66666666666667, 78.4]
```

and data for second model are

```
[80.0, 80.0, 78.66666666666667, 77.46666666666667, 76.8, 75.2, 74.13333333333334, 73.06666666666666].
```

This data are obtained using the simulation of model from time t = 1 to t = 8. I wanted to know which hypothesis test should be performed in order to know these both models are similar or not based on outcomes?

Comment: Belongs on crossvalidated.com.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more difficult than it seems. The classical approach of Haugh works only for stationary time series, and it has been later on extended by Hong. A more recent approach of Duchesne and Roy [http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/pub/Rapports/2700-2799/2751.pdf] should make the Hong's approach more robust to outliers.

Haugh, L. D. (1976), ‘Checking the independence of two covariance-stationary time series: a univariate residual cross-correlation approach’, Journal of American Statistical Association 71, 378–385.

Hong, Y. (1996a), ‘Testing for independence between two covariance stationary time series’, Biometrika 83, 615–625.

Hong, Y. (1996b), ‘A separate mathematical appendix for ’Testing for independence between two covariance stationary time series”, Mimeo, Department of Economics and Department of Statistical Sciences, Cornell University

Answer (score 0):

A 2-sided T-test should be performed since the sample size is so small. Calculate the degrees of freedom, average, and standard deviation of each dataset. Use these statistics to construct a 95% confidence interval. If intervals overlap in anyway, then there is no significant difference between the two data sets. In this case, you have a p-value less than 5%, so there is a significant difference between the two data sets.

```
Two Sample T Test
  Mean and standard deviation
+----------+---------+--------+---+
| Variable |  mean   |   sd   | n |
+----------+---------+--------+---+
| Vector 1 | 79.0833 | 0.5721 | 8 |
| Vector 2 | 76.9167 | 2.6161 | 8 |
+----------+---------+--------+---+

  Levene test for equality of variances : F(1, 14) = 11.9322 , p = 0.0039
  T statistics
+--------------------+--------+--------+----------------+
|        Type        |   t    |   df   | p (both tails) |
+--------------------+--------+--------+----------------+
| Equal variance     | 2.2884 | 14     | 0.0382         |
| Non equal variance | 2.2884 | 7.6680 | 0.0528         |
+--------------------+--------+--------+----------------+

  Effect size
+-------+--------+
| x1-x2 | 2.1667 |
| d     | 1.8345 |
+-------+--------+
```